# Why do I need COUNT(DISTINCT ...) in this MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

I have a system which allows users to create schedules of videos to watch. The following MySQL pulls active schedules and also info on the number of videos in the schedule, the number already watched, and the number due to be watched today. It does this via multiple joins to the same table that tracks schedules-to-videos associations.

```
SELECT
    schedules.*,
    COUNT(DISTINCT sv1.vid_id) AS total_vids, #<-- the problem
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sv1.context_node_id) AS topics,
    COUNT(sv2.vid_id) AS vids_watched,
    COUNT(sv3.vid_id) AS today
FROM schedules
JOIN schedule_vids sv1 ON schedules.id = sv1.schedule_id
LEFT JOIN schedule_vids sv2 ON schedules.id = sv2.schedule_id && sv2.watched IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN schedule_vids sv3 ON schedules.id = sv3.schedule_id && sv3.date = CURDATE()
WHERE user_id = ? && schedules.id = ?
GROUP BY schedules.id
ORDER BY created DESC
```

**The problem:** if I don't use `COUNT (DISTINCT sv1.vid_id)` (i.e. just `COUNT(sv1.vid_id)`) I get a number far in excess of the true number. I've verified this in the DB. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Interestingly, if I remove the join to sv3 (and the corresponding part of the select statement, of course), the problem goes away.

[UPDATE]

Here's the table structure for the two tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE `schedules` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `start` date NOT NULL,
 `end` date NOT NULL,
 `inc_weekends` enum('y') DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` enum('ls','c') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ls' COMMENT 'ls = learning schedule; c = course',
 `subj_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule_vids` (
 `schedule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `vid_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `context_node_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `watched` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`schedule_id`,`vid_id`,`context_node_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Sample output:

```
id              50
name            some-schedule
user_id         yd8i0i63bd8
created         2017-04-01 11:58:22
start           2017-04-01
end             2017-04-03
inc_weekends    y
type            ls
total_vids      91
topics          maths
vids_watched    0
today           91
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help others understand the problem.

Comment: Updating.......

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, you *don't* need the `distinct`.  The problem is your joins.  Use conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT s.*,
       COUNT(*) AS total_vids, #<-- the problem
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sv.context_node_id) AS topics,  -- distinct is probably still needed here
       COUNT(watched) AS vids_watched,
       SUM(sv.date = CURDATE()) AS today
FROM schedules s JOIN
     schedule_vids sv
     ON s.id = sv.schedule_id LEFT JOIN
     school_users su
     ON s.user_id = su.uid  -- I'm guessing `user_id` comes from s
WHERE s.user_id = ? AND s.id = ?
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.created DESC;
```

If you run your query without the aggregation, you'll see what is happening.  You are getting a Cartesian product of videos, which is why the counts are off.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I'm getting "Unknown column 'sv3.date' in 'field list'" - can't see where you define `sv3` as I did, or was I meant to fill that bit in?

Comment: And what's the reason for `SUM()` rather than `COUNT()`?

Comment: I think the sv3 should just be sv, it was left in by accident.

Comment: As for sum Vs count, the expression in the brackets is returning 1s and 0s (or can be treated as though it does). Count would count zeroes, sum avoids that.